# Why am I getting Rails syntax error on params permit action in user_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a user_controller that basically extends the devise user setup, using the following syntax:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.order('created_at DESC').all
    end
    def create
      @user = User.create(user_params)
    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.permit :user (:avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
    end
end
```

In my model user.rb I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
        large: "600x450#",
        medium: "250x250#",
        small: "100x100#"
    }, :default_url => "/images/:style/filler.png"
  #validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :avatar, :email, :password, presence: true


end
```

These all work fine but when I reload the page I get a weird error that says there is a syntax error and its strange because it was working before this. I am assuming its some sort of syntax error with a rails version.

The error is:

```
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-9mVpXM.html
  Message from application: /home/deployer/staging/releases/20140806094001/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...require(:user).permit (:avatar, :email, :password, :password...
...                               ^
/home/deployer/staging/releases/20140806094001/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
...it (:avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
...                               ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Is there anything thats glaringly wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user_params` method is wrong. It should be:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in `user_params`

You need to do like:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

You can read [**more**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: Plus it has syntax error and inconsistent whitespace.

Comment: @MarekLipka Thanks for pointing and downvoting, however, I didn't get where the inconsistent whitespaces are which are causing issue?

Comment: Inconsisted whitespace is fixed now. Though there is still a syntax error in your answer.